# Unauthorized request eventhough permitted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following websecurityconfig and want to allow anyone to access login page but when I try to login, it throws unauthorized exception. When I try to send /user/create request, it works very well and does its job.

```
http.httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.toString())
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/user/remove").hasAnyAuthority(Role.ADMIN.toString(), Role.USER.toString())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/user/create").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "**/login", "login", "/login").permitAll() // trying combinations of login path
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.toString())
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfig(jwtTokenProvider));
```

Here is login controller. I put debugger in the return line and execution does not event come to that point. Security throws the exception.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping // I also tried @RequestMapping({"","/"})
public class PublicController {

@Autowired
AuthenticationService authenticationService;

@PostMapping(value = "login", consumes = "application/json")
public GenericResponse login(@RequestBody UserLoginDTO userLoginDTO) {
    return authenticationService.login(userLoginDTO); // never reached this line
}
}
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Why do you have request mapping at the top of the class? It isn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/login path should not be used for custom login, I tried to change it to /signin and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your complicated antMatcher on just HTTP POST, why not do this:

```
.antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
```

You also need to be able to access your login page via GET, and that simple mapping will do for all your login cases.

Comment: But it is rest api. Not using loginpage or anything. I have custom login method.